# Given a continuous $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ such that $\inf_{t \in [0,t_1)}f(t)=0$ then does for some $0 \le s<t_1$ we have $f(s)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given  a continuous $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ such  that $\inf_{t \in [0,t_1)}f(t)=0$ then does $f(s)=0$ for some $0 \le s<t_1$?

If $t_1=\infty$, then the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}$ and is strictly positive for all values of $t$ and it is not true. I suspect that for a finite $t_1$, there should be an  $0 \le s<t_1$ such that $f(s)=0$. 
I cant think of a such an example. Any hints?

Comment: Why isn't $f(x)=|x-t_1|$ a counterexample to your question? Or is $0$ not supposed to be in the range of $f$?

Comment: Because this $f$  doesnt take the value $0$ in $x \in[0,t_1)$??

Comment: Isn't that what you want to (dis)prove? And what you (dis)proved for $t_1=\infty$!

Comment: i am looking for a counterexample such that $\inf_{t \in [0,t_1)} f(t)=0$ ,$f(s)=0$ for $0 \le s <t_1$.

Comment: Well, in your problem statement you said you wanted a *counterexample* for that. That means you want a function that fullfils $\inf_{t \in [0,t_1)} f(t) = 0$, but doesn't fullfill $f(s)=0$ for some $0 \le s < t_1$. I gave that above. If you now want a *example*, that's even easier: $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume inf f([0,t)) = 0 for some real t.
Then inf f([0,t]) = 0.
Since [0,t] is compact, so is f([0,t]).
Thus some s in [0,1] with f(s) = 0.

Let f(x) = t - x if x <= t, = x - t otherwise.
inf f([0,t)) = 0. f(x) = 0 iff x = t.
As f is continuous, a counterexample ensues.

Comment: The point of the problem, as currently stated, is that $f(s)=0$ needs to be  for some value $s < t$, I repeat *less than t*.

Comment: @Ingix.  Then tought luck, see edit.